# Compare 2 workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 workbooks ( version 1 and version 2 ). I need to compare 2 versions and mark the differences in 2 separate columns as "Present in version1 " and  " not present in version 2". Column structures are same for both versions

I have tried few vba code where it will only highlight the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Many don't realize this but, depending on which version of Office you have, you may have **Spreadsheet Compare** already installed on your system.

- [**Compare two versions of a workbook by using Spreadsheet Compare**](https://support.office.com/article/compare-two-versions-of-a-workbook-by-using-spreadsheet-compare-0e1627fd-ce14-4c33-9ab1-8ea82c6a5a7e)
- [**Basic tasks in Spreadsheet Compare**](https://support.office.com/article/basic-tasks-in-spreadsheet-compare-f2b20af8-a6d3-4780-8011-f15b3229f5d8)
- [**Overview of Spreadsheet Compare**](https://support.office.com/article/overview-of-spreadsheet-compare-13fafa61-62aa-451b-8674-242ce5f2c986)

[image: img]

To find out if you have it, hit your <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> Windows key and type `spreadsheet compare`.

There are sites that claim to have free downloadable versions - but I can't vouch for their legitimacy.